# ogr2ogr error: Couldn't fetch requested layer when appending multiple geopackages

Tags: gdal, geopackage

I've got two geopackages and I want to combine them to the output ‘output.gpkg’. One of my geopackage contains reference master tables (20 tables) and the another one contains dynamic information (5 tables).

> ogr2ogr -f "gpkg" output.gpkg reference.gpkg dynamic.gpkg

I ran into the error ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'dynamic.gpkg'!
What could have caused this error? I’m using GDAL 3.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ogr2ogr` syntax is

```
ogr2ogr [options] dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name [layer [layer ...]]
```

So your syntax says convert the layer `dynamic.gpkg` from the source dataset `reference.gpkg` into the destination dataset `output.gpkg`.

There's no simple syntax for specifying multiple source datasets.  There's probably a complex way to do it using a SQL statement with a `UNION` operator, but I haven't tried that as it's pretty simple to just do the following:

You can copy dynamic.gpkg to a new gpkg and append to it with `ogr2ogr`

```
ogr2ogr -f "gpkg" output.gpkg reference.gpkg
ogr2ogr -f "gpkg" -update -append output.gpkg dynamic.gpkg
```

Or you can try the python script [`ogrmerge.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html)

```
ogrmerge.py -f "gpkg" -nln "{LAYER_NAME}" -o output_ogrmerge.gpkg reference.gpkg dynamic.gpkg
```

Note: on Windows, you may need to find where `ogrmerge.py` is installed and use:

```
python C:\path\to\ogrmerge.py -f "gpkg" -nln "{LAYER_NAME}" -o output_ogrmerge.gpkg reference.gpkg dynamic.gpkg
```

[image]